# Bitwise XOR on structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct, bitwise-xor

What I want to do is a bitwise XOR on two variables of the same struct in C++, i.e.

```
    D[i] ^= D[j];
```

where D is an Array containing strings, int, ....

However, the compiler complains (here using an integer array as index, meaning D[dInd[u]]^=...):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
no match for ‘operator^=’ in ‘*(D + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)
(*(dInd + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)u) * 4ul))))) * 2808ul))) 
^= *(D + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)(*(dInd + ((long unsigned 
int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 4ul))))) * 2808ul)))’
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can correct this line in order to achieve the bitwise XOR?

Any hints are very apreciated. Thanks in advance, cheers
- alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload the member in the struct:

```
struct X
{
   X& operator ^= (const X& other)
   {
       //...
       return *this;
   }
};
```

Comment: and if you want to write D[i] ^ D[j] then you can override the next operator - 
'X operator ^ (const X& b1, const X& b2);'

Comment: Thank you Luchian for your answer! Since there are several encapsulated structs of which some I shouldn't touch, I will mix the overloading with some functions that perform the XOR operation..

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky... you can either XOR by reinterpreting the structures as a contiguous area of data of an XOR-able type, or think about how to XOR each data member in turn.  Both approaches have issues you'll need to consider, and which is best depends on why you're doing it.

For example:

```
struct X
{
    X& operator^=(const X& rhs)
    {
        // WARNING: this won't follow pointers to "owned" data
        unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)this;
        unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*)&rhs;
        size_t size = sizeof *this;
        while (size--)
            *p++ ^= *q++;
    }
};
```

v.s.

```
    X& operator^=(const X& rhs)
    {
        my_int ^= rhs.my_int;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof my_int_array / sizeof my_int_array[0]; ++i)
             my_int_array[i] ^= rhs.my_int_array[i];

        // WARNING: this won't XOR the string object's embedded data members -
        //          typically a pointer to the text, a size & capacity etc..
        std::string::const_iterator j = rhs.my_string.begin();
        for (std::string::iterator i = my_string.begin(); i != my_string.end() && j != rhs.my_string.end(); ++i, ++j)
            *i ^= *j;

        // note: you'll have to decide what to do for different-length string data, doubles etc.
    }
```

Note that this xoring invalidates members like pointers and doubles - you shouldn't even read from them as those types unless you've xored again to restore the original values.

Comment: Thanks @TonyDelroy for your answer! That's exactly an issue where I'm stuck right now - how to XOR char*[]'s of different length.. i guess the shorter one will just have zero bits on the 'missing' bits...

Comment: By the way: Shouln't it be i++ and j++ up in your code? This way, you'd start from my_int_array[1] which is the second element, isn't it?

Comment: @astriffe: it is already, just in the loop increment statement rather than as side effects on the XOR.  Gotta scroll the code to see it (annoying on Safari where there's no scrollbar, but the usual two-finger drag works).